# SwiftUI SecureField: How to achieve the same character obscuring behaviour as in UIKit?

Tags: swiftui, uitextfield

My problem is `SecureField` in SwiftUI doesn’t display characters input by the user for any time at all, it just directly shows the '•' symbol for each character as it's typed - whereas in UIKit, `UITextField` (with `isSecureTextEntry = true`) shows the latest character for a second before hiding it behind '•'.

UX testers at my company have requested I bring back the "old behaviour" - but this behaviour doesn't seem part of any public API.

Interestingly this goes for `UITextField` custom classes injected into SwiftUI using `UIViewRepresentable` too - they behave in the "SwiftUI way" described above. So there's some contextual behaviour modification going on in SwiftUI for all secure `UITextField` behaviour? I'd have to completely rewrite my SwiftUI form into a full `UIViewController` to get back the behaviour (modally pushed UIViewControllers with secure UITextFields **do** exhibit the desired behaviour.)

Is this a sort of sideline bug in SwiftUI? I see the same thing for SwiftUI in both iOS13 and 14. Anyone seen a workaround or solution?

-EDIT-

After @Asperi's great explanation below, I noticed that my `UITextField` custom classes injected into SwiftUI using `UIViewRepresentable` were forcing this behaviour by unnecessarily setting the text binding in the `updateUIView` call. Using a Coordinator only to deal with text logic fixed the problem for me when using this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The observed effect is due to immediate apply to bound string state and immediate react/rebuild of view.

To bring desired behavior beck we need to postpone somehow state update and thus give a chance for SecuredField/UITextField to update self without synchronisation with state.

Here is a demo of possible direction (it is not ideal, but a way to go). Tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1.

[image: demo]

```
struct DemoSecureFieldView: View {
    @State private var password = "demo"

    var textBinding: Binding<String>  {
        Binding(get: { password },
            set: { value in
                // more logic can be added to delay _only_ if new symbol added,
                // and force apply if next symbol came fast
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.25) {
                    password = value
                }
            }
        )
    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            SecureField("Placeholder", text: textBinding)
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    .padding()
        }.background(Color.pink)
    }
}
```

Comment: Wonderful, thanks! Turns out my `UITextField` injection via `UIViewRepresentable` made this even easier, and I'd just wired it up "too tight" by setting the value of my text binding in `updateUIView`. But I had a coordinator so that was unnecessary anyway.

Comment: It does not work in iOS 15